# Add markers in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is the code:

```
<div class="mgn-top-10">
                      <asp:Label ID="lbcontact" runat="server" ></asp:Label>



  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var lat = document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML;
            var lan = document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML;
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lan),
                zoom: 14,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
                document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML= e.latLng.lat();
                document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = e.latLng.lng();

            });

        }

 </script>

            <asp:Label ID="latitude" runat="server" ForeColor ="#f8f5f5" ></asp:Label>

               <asp:Label ID="longitude" runat="server" ForeColor ="#f8f5f5" ></asp:Label>

    <div id="dvMap" style="width: 700px; height: 300px">
    </div>   </div>
```

I have reused Google Maps code written in asp.net, I want to add a marker in map's, it's currently my university task.

Please help me out.

Google map's are already working perfectly but no marker's.

Thanks in advance

as suggested:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var lat = document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML;
            var lan = document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML;
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lan),
                zoom: 14,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
            var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
});
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
                document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML= e.latLng.lat();
                document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = e.latLng.lng();

            });

        }

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#add):

```
var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
});
```

The result using your edited code looks like this:

[image]

If you want to add markers when the user clicks the map you can do it like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
    document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML= e.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = e.latLng.lng();
    var myLatLng = {lat: e.latLng.lat(), lng: e.latLng.lng()};
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });
});
```

Comment: question updated as per on your suggestion but didn't worked.

Comment: It work's but it work's when we click in to map, i want to add marker in the maps by default...

Comment: The first code I posted does exactly this, it adds a Marker on Australia by default